I cant find my wifi icon or my wifi settings
I am unable to find my WiFi settings. I tried multiple troubleshooting methods. Please help.

On running sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade, this is the error I got:




On running sudo apt install --reinstall NetworkManager, it said
unable to locate package NetworkManager:



sudo systemctl status NetworkManager showed this:



Please [edit] your question and give us some context. As it stands, we know nothing about the situation. What desktop environment (which Ubuntu flavor) are you using? What are the multiple methods you tried (if you don't tell us, we will waste your time suggesting the things you have already tried)?. What is your hardware? Is this a laptop? A desktop? Is this an Ubuntu server installation or regular Ubuntu? What settings are you looking for?

My Ubuntu version is 20.04. It is dualbooted with windows 11.  I have edited my question with the troubleshooting I tried. Since Im new here, I could only add links to the error images. Thanks a lot for considering.

Thanks!  Please don't post images of text though. Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the formatting tools to format it as code. Have you looked at the network settings in the GUI?

yes, I did. I could only see settings for VPN, not WiFi.
